# フィルタの閲覧数での並べ替えが機能して無さそうです→翻訳違い

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

現時点ではこんな結果で、閲覧数でソートされているようには見えません。
[image: 並べ替え結果]

---

追記：
機能と翻訳が合っていなかったとのこと。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「閲覧数」と翻訳されていますが、実際にはサイト内で**リンクされた回数**で並べ替えが行われているようです。いずれにせよ、当該オプションは閲覧数でのソートではないため、翻訳を修正する必要があると思います。

> #### What does the Frequent tab mean?<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344306)</sup>
>
> The questions with the most links to them are displayed in the Frequent tab.
>
> Those links might be in other questions, in answers, comments, or in the duplicate header added when a question is closed as a duplicate.
>
> Essentially, these are the most-referenced questions.

また、過去に閲覧数による並べ替えの実装が提案されていますが、これは以下の理由で却下されています<sup>[[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113042)</sup>。

- 閲覧数での並べ替えは頻繁に使用しない
- 絶えず変化する閲覧数によるソートを実現することが困難

もし現在、閲覧数での検索結果の絞り込みをしたい場合には、 [`views` 範囲演算子](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)もしくは [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53412) を用いて対応することになります。

---

### 追記

当該箇所の翻訳が「リンク最多」に更新されたため、この問題は改善されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

参考:

- [What does the Frequent tab mean? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344306)
- [Can we have a sort by view count? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113042)
- [検索の方法は？ - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: なるほど、プログラム修正よりは実態に合わせた文言の修正の方が良さそうですね。

Comment: おそらく[このstring](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/11379)なので、[他の用法](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5BfF%5Drequent)と合わせて「リンク最多」に訳語を変えるのを Traducir で提案してみました。